# Extracting data from a table getting only the last row

Tags: python

I have the following table from this [website](http://archive.ifrs.org/Use-around-the-world/Pages/Analysis-of-the-IFRS-jurisdictional-profiles.aspx) :

```
<table id="sample">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="toprow">
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="5">Number of Jurisdictions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="toprow">
            <td>Region</td>
            <td>Jurisdictions in the region</td>
            <td>Jurisdictions that require IFRS&nbsp;Standards&nbsp;<br>
            for all or most domestic publicly accountable entities</td>
            <td>Jurisdictions that require IFRS Standards&nbsp;as % of total jurisdictions in the region</td>
            <td>Jurisdictions that permit or require IFRS&nbsp;Standards for at least some (but not all or most) domestic publicly accountable entities</td>
            <td>Jurisdictions that neither require nor permit IFRS Standards for any domestic publicly accountable entities</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftcol">Europe</td>
            <td class="data">44</td>
            <td class="data">43</td>
            <td class="data">98%</td>
            <td class="data">1</td>
            <td class="data">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftcol">Africa</td>
            <td class="data">23</td>
            <td class="data">19</td>
            <td class="data">83%</td>
            <td class="data">1</td>
            <td class="data">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftcol">Middle East</td>
            <td class="data">13</td>
            <td class="data">13</td>
            <td class="data">100%</td>
            <td class="data">0</td>
            <td class="data">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftcol">Asia-Oceania</td>
            <td class="data">33</td>
            <td class="data">24</td>
            <td class="data">73%</td>
            <td class="data">3</td>
            <td class="data">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftcol">Americas</td>
            <td class="data">37</td>
            <td class="data">27</td>
            <td class="data">73%</td>
            <td class="data">8</td>
            <td class="data">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftcol" style="border-top:2px solid #000000"><strong>Totals</strong></td>
            <td class="data" style="border-top:2px solid #000000"><strong>150</strong></td>
            <td class="data" style="border-top:2px solid #000000"><strong>126</strong></td>
            <td class="data" style="border-top:2px solid #000000"><strong>84%</strong></td>
            <td class="data" style="border-top:2px solid #000000"><strong>13</strong></td>
            <td class="data" style="border-top:2px solid #000000"><strong>11</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftcol"><strong>As % <br>
            of 150</strong></td>
            <td class="data"><strong>100%</strong></td>
            <td class="data"><strong>84%</strong></td>
            <td class="data"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
            <td class="data"><strong>9%</strong></td>
            <td class="data"><strong>7%</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my following attempt :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import requests
# Site URL
url = "http://archive.ifrs.org/Use-around-the-world/Pages/Analysis-of-the-IFRS-jurisdictional-profiles.aspx"
# Make a GET request to fetch the raw HTML content
html_content = requests.get(url).text
# Parse HTML code for the entire site
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
# print(soup.prettify()) # print the parsed data of html
# On site there are 3 tables with the class "wikitable"
# The following line will generate a list of HTML content for each table
gdp = soup.select("table#sample")[0]
rows = []
cols = []
for g in gdp.select('tr.toprow'):
    for c in g.select('td'):
        cols.append(c.text)
    
for g in gdp.select('tr:not(.toprow)'):
    row = []
    for item in g.select('td'):
        row.append(item.text)
    rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
```

The problem is cols is getting the right result :

```
['', 'Number of Jurisdictions', 'Region', 'Jurisdictions in the region', 'Jurisdictions that require IFRS\xa0Standards\xa0\r\n        
    for all or most domestic publicly accountable entities', 'Jurisdictions that require IFRS Standards\xa0as % of total jurisdictions in the region', 'Jurisdictions that permit or require IFRS\xa0Standards for at least some (but not all or most) domestic publicly accountable entities', 'Jurisdictions that neither require nor permit IFRS Standards for any domestic publicly accountable entities']
```

The problem is with the rows, it's getting me only the last row :

```
['As % \r\n            of 150', '100%', '84%', '\xa0', '9%', '7%']
```

I am getting this error :

> ValueError: 8 columns passed, passed data had 6 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is two tr with .toprow, skip the first .toprow

```
for g in gdp.select('tr.toprow')[1:]:
```

Your solution will look like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
gdp = soup.select("table#sample")[0]
rows = []
cols = []
for g in gdp.select('tr.toprow')[1:]:
    for c in g.select('td'):
        cols.append(c.text)
    
for g in gdp.select('tr:not(.toprow)'):
    row = []
    for item in g.select('td'):
        row.append(item.text)
    rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
```